# What does the acf of the log of data tell us?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

I'm working with  **time series data**. And there is a use of `acf` ( auto correlation function ) being applied to the `log` of a series.

Basically the `log` of the data with `acf` was the correct way while the `acf` without `log` was not.

Why I would use a `log` function in a **auto correlation function.** ??

Example:

```
Acf(log(data)) # correct 
Acf(data) # wrong
```

Please any help would be great.

Comment: Did you log the data or ACF?

Comment: Sometimes, when you deal with strictly positive data like stock-prices, then a possible model is that the data are lognormally distributed. When you take the log of the data, you get a different time-series with  normally distributed data. You can then go on to study the spectral and periodicity properties of this resulting signal using ACF/DFT etc. It would help if you could provide more context.

Comment: @Aksakal just updated the question. I log the data.

Comment: @Salmonstrikes yes it's a stock data. And all the values are positive. Can you tell me why it's necessary make the log normally in the data ? What I can get with this aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because stock prices are usually assumed to follow a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) (if we assume infinitesimal stock price changes are normally distributed, like the usual [Black-Scholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model) model).

Also, if you look at log-stock-prices, you'll definitely find autocorrelations... more interesting would be to find autocorrelations in the *change* in stock prices.

Comment: When you say the change it would be the perceptual change or just the value ?

Comment: The black scholes model assumes that infinitesimal changes are normally distributed. If you calculate the percentage change in price in a small enough interval, the log-normal distribution will be approximately normal.